# recursive maps and decimal representation

Tags: computability

I'm trying to think of an example of a real number $R$ such that the map $n \mapsto R[n]$, where $R[n]$ is the $n$th digit of the decimal representation of $R$, is not recursive.

So I was thinking to take an irrational number such as $\pi$, or $e$. Then can we argue by Church's thesis? What better examples are there?

Comment: Most numbers are like this, as there are only countably many algorithms and uncountably many reals.  But exhibiting one is very difficult.  Most reasonable ways of describing a number provide an algorithm.

Comment: In computability, the distinction between reals (in $[0,1]$) and subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ is (justifiably) blurred. All you're really asking for is a non-computable set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\pi$ and $e$ won't do it; they are eminently recursive, because we have algorithms that calculate the $n$th digit of each.

Any such number must be very weird, and (obviously) its exact numerical value must be unknown.  [Chaitin's constant](http://enwp.org/Chaitin%27s_constant) is an example.  But here is an even simpler example: Let $M$ be an enumeration of turing machines.  Let $R$ be such that $R[n]$ is 1 if $M(n)$ halts on all inputs, and 0 if there is some input on which $M(n)$ does not halt.  Then $R$ is clearly non recursive; if $R$ were recursive, the halting problem would be solvable.  The Chaitin construction is similar.  Chaitin's constant $\Omega$ is a number which in a certain sense represents the probability that a randomly-selected turing machine will halt.

Comment: Can you give some more examples of something that I could better see it? Also, can you please justify why your constant is an example. Thanks